# PWM logic level issue

Tags: pwm, stm32, logic-level

I am facing new problems everyday at embedded system. I have designed D-SMPS  and put an stm32f103 to drive mosfets.I have tested micro controller and it works well while giving outputs as GPIO.It is seen at image.
[image]
I have given 1ms delay to see square wave.

But when it comes to use TIMER PWM , logic level is not correct.
[image]

It is reducing to 1V. I have no idea why same pin gives different reaction at same point.
[image]

Do you guys have any idea how it may happen?

Comment: Is your oscilloscope set up exactly the same way for each test (including which channel is "active")?  Are the PWM pins driving anything?  Is the port setup exactly the same?  Can you go back and forth between GPIO and PWM and see this effect repeat?  It is very strange to me, too -- I've used that part to drive motors, and it certainly didn't do that to me.

Comment: The first signal is 250 Hz, the second is apparently 50 kHz. What happens if you toggle the pin as GPIO, but with 50 kHz frequency?

Comment: Quite likely, one cannot drive a mosfet directly from a uP. One needs a mosfet driver for it. Not sure what you did as you showed half the circuit: it is at least missing the mosfets themselves...

Comment: @TimWescott Yes I set up the test system. And even I did not show remained circuit there are two L6388 Mosfet driver to drive full bridge topology. I would say that my hardware have some issue if logic level issue occurs at GPIO settings ,too.

Comment: @berendi I have changed frequency from 15 khz to 100khz but same issue occured.

Comment: @Huisman I did not think that the logic level issue happens because of mosfet driver would you want me to add that circuit pieces too?

Comment: Just a tip: when you capture oscilloscope pic, please take complete display which will cover, horizontal and vertical scale along with any other info displayed

Comment: any updates?....

Comment: @Umar What you recommend as a way did not work. I have removed mosfet drivers and it started work well.

Comment: MSOFET drivers or MOSFETs .. can you also show them in schematics?

Answer (score -1):

Which is the Pin you are worried about? Here is how you can go about finding the root cause.

1. Make sure the power supply is stable. Measure the 3 V supply
2. Make sure the **GPIO pin is disconnected electrically from all** the components. Remove series component if any or lift the MOSFET if it is connected.
3. Drive a test frequency signal and monitor waveform (you have done it for 250 Hz)
4. Enable PWM and drive it again with lower frequency
5. Increase the frequency to higher value (actual value)
6. PWM is a Digital output toggled at higher frequency. Hence, the Singal level on oscilloscope MUST reach 3.3V or the MCU VDD how much ever it is
7. Please post complete schematics section and if the GPIO outmode is able to drive the signal to complete logic 1 and logic zero,there is no way a healthy MCU would fail to create the same logic 1 and logic 0 signal for PWM.
8. I suspect that the pin is getting loaded but we will see when you share the complete schematics related to PWM pin part
9. Pleas verify once that the probes are with high impedance DC coupling settings

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/231493)

Comment: @OlegMazurov updated to actually help as answer